# How to import API widget into Vue 3 component?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to **import a API widget football league standings**.
According to the documentation [api-football](https://www.api-football.com/documentation-v3#tag/Widgets/operation/get-widget-standings) I should copy

```
<div id="wg-api-football-standings"
    data-host="v3.football.api-sports.io"
    data-key="Your-Api-Key-Here"
    data-league="39"
    data-team=""
    data-season="2021"
    data-theme=""
    data-show-errors="false"
    data-show-logos="true"
    class="wg_loader">
</div>
<script
    type="module"
    src="https://widgets.api-sports.io/2.0.3/widgets.js">
</script>
```

Of course it doesnt work in my component because 
`[plugin:vite:vue] Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates.`

If i copy this to index.html and just div id into my component the widget is loading but not successfully. How should I import script if I have export default with name attribute?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? 
This is a api so you have to do request on wath data you want, you can see a example ir https://www.api-football.com/documentation-v3#section/Sample-Scripts/Javascript

Comment: the [widget](https://www.api-football.com/news/post/how-custom-api-football-widgets) is not compatible as a Vue component.  whoever made it intended it for use within vanilla javascript web apps